# wrong argument type Class (expected Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, model-view-controller, module

I am new to rails. I have a class in my lib directory and I am trying to create a object of that class in my controller action. This is throwing me an error when I am loading my view, Error Message ::"wrong argument type Class (expected Module)". However if I embed my class in a module(same class in the lib directory) and create an object like Module::classname.new it doesn't give me any error. Does that mean that all the classes in the lib directory have to be embedded inside a module ?

My code :

controller Code :

```
require 'names_helper'

class NamesController < ApplicationController
  def receive_names
    if request.post?
      NamesHelper.new.func()
    else
      puts "inside get"
    end
  end
end
```

My names_helper file code (this file is my lib directory)

```
class NamesHelper
  def func
  end
end
```

Comment: It would help your case greatly if you posted the code in question (how are you trying to instantiate your class, and how does the class in which you try to instantiate the first class know about that first class -- i.e. did you `require` the class?). If you post code, then you keep people from wasting time guessing.

Comment: Do you also have a NameHelper module? (Rails would have created this for you if you used one of the generators)

Answer (score 1):

First of all on your Q,

`Does that mean that all the classes in the lib directory have to be embedded inside a module ?` - No, its not necessary.

And the code you explain should work fine unless there was a name conflict. That is having `NamesHelper` already defined as a module (either Rails in built or you define in your app). Please make sure this.

I guess similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26256737/5076451

Comment: yes, I changed the name of my class to some other thing and it worked. Thanks !!